# JAXP XpathFactory Object model

Tags: java, xml, xpath, jaxp

What is the OBJECT MODEL in `XPathFactory` ?

What is important for?

Does it affect the application performance?

The spec and the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html) claims that the default object model is the following:

`DEFAULT_OBJECT_MODEL_URI = "http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom"`

But on [saxon documentation](http://saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!xpath-api/jaxp-xpath/factory) I found others

- http://jdom.org/jaxp/xpath/jdom
- http://www.xom.nu/jaxp/xpath/xom
- http://www.dom4j.org/jaxp/xpath/dom4j
- http://saxon.sf.net/jaxp/xpath/om

The object model is selected as below:

```
String objectModel = "http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom";
XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance(objectModel);
XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();
```

Answer (score 0):

JAXP provides a default implementation for the DEFAULT_OBJECT_MODEL_URI which is the w3c DOM. If you have jdom in your classpath then you can specify that XPathFactory use the JDOM Document Object model. Look at [this](http://www.studytrails.com/java/xml/jdom2/java-xml-jdom2-xpath.jsp) example to see JDOM2 XPath example and [this](http://www.studytrails.com/java/xml/jaxp/java-api-for-xml-xpath.jsp) link to see JAXP XPath example